# Content-only Nuget package fails to restore content

Tags: c#, nuget

I've created a content-only Nuget package that adds a text file to the project it's installed into. I checked in the project *without* the text file as I want it to be restored during `nuget restore`. All is well until the CI machine tries to restore the package. The restore succeeds but the text file is not added. Apparently, nuget thinks that the text file already exists since there is a reference to it in the project file.

How do I get nuget to restore the text file?

Essentially, the behaviour I want is the same as with DLL files: when a package is installed, references to DLLs are added to the project; when the package is restored, DLLs are restored to satisfy the references in the project file. I want the same behaviour but for text files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was putting the text file into the top-level folder like this (a snippet from my .nuspec):

```
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="dictionary.txt" target="dictionary.txt" />
    </files>
</package>
```

So when the package is installed, the file is put into `/packages/MyPackage.0.0.6` and referenced from the .csproj like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\MyPackage.0.0.6\dictionary.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then the file is read from .cs like this:

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
             .GetManifestResourceStream(GetType(), "dictionary.txt");
```

This got me the desired behaviour: when the package is restored, the file is restored and put exactly where the reference is pointing to.